# FetchResultsController sorting issue

Tags: ios, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nssortdescriptor

I have an NSFetchResultsController initialised with an NSSortDescriptor that sorts according to the `localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:` method.

Entities are sorted on their last name, however some of them don't specify their last name and hence, the char 170 (in ASCII) is set as their last name (don't ask me why, the source code is done that way and I rather don't change it). When sorted, these persons "without last name" are displayed at the top of the table view. I would like them to be at the end of it.

Seems that it is not possible to use specific NSSortDescriptor in my case (i'm using a FRC), what are my options here ?

[EDIT]
Comparator blocks or custom comparator methods won't work with NSFetchResultsController

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your options are limited as the sort descriptor needs to be able to work with an SQLite data store.

You should edit the data model so you have an attribute that you can sort on. Exactly how you calculate the value is up to you, but the attribute can't be temporary. I would suggest that you either:

1. Implement `willSave` in your `NSManagedObject` subclass to create / update the sort data
2. Or, make your sort data a dependent key (using `KVO`, again in your `NSManagedObject` subclass)

Your sort data could be as simple as:

```
self.sortValue = (self.lastName == 170 in ASCII ? @"ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ" : lastName)
```